# Nullpointerexception uing a cursor in asynctask

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am stupmed on this.  I am following along with a project in the book and if I use the books example file this works.  However is I use my file which as far as I can see is identical, I get a nullpointer exception.  Here is the file below:

```
//AddressBook.java
//Main activity for address book app.
package com.deitel.addressbook;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;


public class AddressBook extends ListActivity {

    //string used when logging for debug
    public static final String TAG ="AddressBookBot";

    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";  //Intent extra key
    private ListView contactListView;  //the ListActivity's ListView
    private CursorAdapter contactAdapter;  //adapter for ListView

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  //call super's onCreate
        Log.d(TAG, "In onCreate() event");
        contactListView = getListView();
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListener);

        //map each contact's name to a TV in the ListView layout
        String[] from = {"name"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.contactTextView};
        CursorAdapter contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddressBook.this,
                R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);    
        setListAdapter(contactAdapter);  //set contactView's adapter
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){

        Log.d(TAG, "In onResume() event");
        super.onResume();  //call super's onResume method

        //create a new GetContactsTask and execute it
        new GetContactsTask().execute((Object[]) null);
    }  //end onResume

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){

        Log.d(TAG, "In onStop() event");
        Cursor cursor = contactAdapter.getCursor();  //get current Cursor
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();  //deactivate it

        contactAdapter.changeCursor(null);  //adapter now has no Cursor
        super.onStop();
    }  //end onStop

    //performs database query outside GUI thread
    private class GetContactsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor>{        

        DatabaseConnector DBC = new DatabaseConnector(AddressBook.this);

        //perform the database access
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params){
            DBC.open();

            //get a cursor containing call contacts
            return DBC.getAllContacts();
        }  //end method doInBackground

        //use the Cursor returned from the doInBackground method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result){
            Log.d(TAG, "In onPostExecute() event");
            contactAdapter.changeCursor(result);  //set the adapter's Cursor
            DBC.close();
        }  //end method onPostExecute
    }  //end class GetContactsTask

    //create the Activity's menu from a menu resource XML file  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addressbook_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }  //end onCreateOptionsMenu

    //handle the choice from options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        //create a new Intent to launch the AddEditContact Activity
        Intent addNewContact = new Intent(AddressBook.this, AddEditContact.class);
        startActivity(addNewContact);  //start the AddEditContact Activity
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  //call super's method
    }  //end onOptionsItemSelected

    //event listener that responds to the users touching a contact's name in the ListView
    OnItemClickListener viewContactListener = new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

            //create an Intent to launch the ViewContact Activity
            Intent viewContact = new Intent(AddressBook.this, ViewContact.class);

            //pass the selected contact's row ID as an extra with the intent
            viewContact.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
            startActivity(viewContact);  //start the ViewContact Activity           
        }  //end method onItemClick
    };  //end viewContactListener
}  //end class AddressBook
```

the problem seems to be this line in my "getContactsTask" inner class:
    contactAdapter.changeCursor(result); 
Once I hit this line I get a nullpointer exception.  For reference, here is the database connector class I am referencing in getContactsTask:

```
//DatabaseConnector.java
//Provides easy connection and creation of UserContacts database.
package com.deitel.addressbook;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseConnector {

    public static final String TAG ="AddressBookBot";

    //database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserContacts";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;  //database object
    private DatabaseOpenHelper DBOpenHelper;  //database helper

    //public constructor for DatabaseConnector
    public DatabaseConnector(Context context){

        //create a new DatabaseOpenHelper
        DBOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }  //end constructor

    //open the database connection
    public void open() throws SQLException{

        //create or open a database for reading/writing
        database = DBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }  //end method open

    //close the database connection
    public void close(){

        if(database != null)
            database.close();  //close database connection
    }  //end method close

    //inserts a new contact in the database
    public void insertContact(String name, String email, String phone, String state, String city){

        ContentValues newContact = new ContentValues();
        newContact.put("name", name);
        newContact.put("email", email);
        newContact.put("phone", phone);
        newContact.put("street", state);
        newContact.put("city", city);

        open();  //open the database
        database.insert("contacts", null, newContact);
        close();  //close the database
    }  //end insertContact

    //inserts a new contact in the database
    public void updateContact(long id, String name, String email, String phone, String state, String city){

        ContentValues editContact = new ContentValues();
        editContact.put("name", name);
        editContact.put("email", email);
        editContact.put("phone", phone);
        editContact.put("street", state);
        editContact.put("city", city);

        open();  //open the database
        database.update("contacts", editContact, "_id=" + id, null);
        close();  //close the database
    }  //end updateContact

    //return a Cursor with all contact information in the database
    public Cursor getAllContacts(){
        Log.d(TAG, "in getAllContacts");
        return database.query("contacts", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, null, null, null, null, "name");

    }  //end getAllContacts

    //get a Cursor containing all information about the contact specified by the given id
    public Cursor getOneContact(long id){

        return database.query("contacts", null, "_id='" + id, null, null, null, null);
    }  //end getOneContact

    //delete the contact specified by the given String name
    public void deleteContact(long id){

        open();  //open the database
        database.delete("contacts", "_id=" + id, null);
        close();  //close the database
    }  //end deleteContact

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        //public constructor
        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version){
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }  //end DatabaseOpenHelper contstructor

        //creates the contacts table when the database is created
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

            //query to create a new table named contacts
            String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE contacts" + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement," + "name TEXT, email TEXT, phone TEXT," + "street TEXT, city TEXT);";

            db.execSQL(createQuery);  //execute the query
        }  //end method onCreate

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

        }  //end onUpgrade
    }  //end class DatabaseOpenHelper   
}  //end class DataBaseConnector
```

Any help or clarity on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did wrong:

I declare a

```
private CursorAdapter contactAdapter;
```

in the AddressBook.java file.  Then later on instead of putting

```
contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddressBook.this,
                R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);
```

I declare it again on the spot

```
CursorAdapter contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(AddressBook.this,
                R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);
```

this causes a null pointer exception.  After cleaning up the 2nd declare error the app runs just fine.  Thanks again to all who helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Cursor object is refrencing to null i think . The result refrence variable is ponting to which query?

Comment: Yeah the cursor is referencing null for sure but I cannot understand why.  Nothing looks out of place here.  As for the result reference, I am pretty sure the 'result' is referencing the return from getAllContacts.

Answer (score 0):

You did not open the database before making a query in getAllContacts(). 
The function should look like:

```
public Cursor getAllContacts() {
    Log.d(TAG, "in getAllContacts");

    Cursor cursor = null;

    open();   // open the database
    cursor = database.query("contacts", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                         null, null, null, null, "name");
    close(); // close the database

    return cursor;
}
```

Similar issue is there in the function getOneContact() too.

Comment: doInBackground opens the database when called and (I assume) gives the results from the return DBC.getAllContacts(); to onPostExecute which then should read the cursor that is set up.  This is my understanding of how AsyncTask should function but I may be incorrect.